# I have pattern matching problem in case command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I usually use pattern matching in [[ command,
but I wanted to use it in case command.

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -version|head -1
# Test 1:
[[ apple79 == apple@(14|38|79|11) ]] && echo ok 1
# Test2:
case apple79 in apple@(14|38|79|11)) echo ok 2;; *) ;; esac
```

When I run the above `test.sh` at terminal with `.` command everything is normal.

```
. test.sh
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
ok 1
ok 2
```

But when I try to run it so:

```
./t.sh
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
ok 1
./t.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./t.sh: line 6: `    case apple79 in apple@(14|38|79|11)) echo ok 2;; *) ;; esac'
```

I have received an error messages for the case command.
I have seen some bash pattern matching doc eg.:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/pattern-matching-bash
But I have no any idea for this problem.

Comment: Try adding `shopt extglob` and recreate your tests. You will find it `on` when sourced. Because mostly likely you have it enabled it on the command line and sourcing it is taking that option from there

Comment: @Inian Starting in `bash` 4.1, "Force extglob on temporarily when parsing the pattern argument to
    the == and != operators to the [[ command, for compatibility."

Comment: Yes @chepner, but  that does not apply to `case` pattern matching too right? Because that doesn't explain why sourcing works for the case too right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most likely because you have turned on `extglob` option in your current shell. Because sourcing the script takes the current shell's options and extended options, it works when sourcing the script.

But when doing the `./t.sh` you are launching an explicit shell which does not have the option turned on by default. Since `[[` operator with `==` turns on `extglob` by default, it works for the first test but fails for the `case` statement. To enable the option explicitly in scripts do `shopt -s extglob` at the top of your script.

As you can see below the pattern works with `case` only if the option is enabled. Try removing `-O extglob` from below command and you can see it doesn't work.

```
bash -O extglob -c 'case apple79 in apple@(14|38|79|11)) echo ok 2;; *) ;; esac'
```

---

As far why your attempt didn't work, try adding a line `shopt extglob` to your `t.sh` and repeat your tests. You'll notice that when the script is sourced you'll see `extglob         on` and for the executed case get `extglob         off`

Comment: Thanks @Inian   Is there a way to see what kind of bash options turned on when I opened the terminal eg.: under ubuntu?

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi: On terminal, doing `echo $-` provides you all the [shell options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) and typing `shopt` shows you the list of [extended options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin). See [4.3 Modifying Shell Behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Modifying-Shell-Behavior.html#Modifying-Shell-Behavior)

Comment: Thanks @Inian for your useful and detailed info.
When I see the difference of the ext.opt. of the two type bash shells 
`diff <(shopt) <(bash -c 'shopt')`
I can see also why I couldn't use aliases in my bash scripts in the past.

Answer (score 3):

The `extglob` option is implicitly enabled inside `[[ ... ]]` for pattern matching, but you need to enable it explicitly to use it with the `case` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

[[ apple79 == apple@(14|38|79|11) ]] && echo ok 1
case apple79 in apple@(14|38|79|11)) echo ok 2;; *) ;; esac
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is between interactive and non-interactive shell options.
By default extglob are turned off for non-interactive shells, so you can do:

```
bash -i t.sh
```

or add

```
shopt -s extglob
```

at the beginning of your script

Comment: That is not quite right. Even in interactive shells, it’s not enabled by default. Only when turned on explicitly

Comment: Ok, maybe it depends on distributive. I have tested on ubuntu and got the same behaviour.